# asp.net bundle file contents are not being uploaded on publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I published my asp.net application using publish option in Visual studio. and it published without any error.

But When I ran application, I noticed it has not uploaded contents for `customcss` and `customjs` bundles on ftp. Even physical files are not uploaded. everything works fine on local

Am I missing something here.

I have following code in my layout and bundleconfig files.

in _Layout.cshtml file

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/customcss")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/customjs")
```

in BundleConfig.cs File

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/customcss").Include(
                    "~/Content/css/normalize.css",
                    "~/Content/css/colorbox.css",
                    "~/Content/css/main.css",
                    "~/Content/css/global.css"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/customjs").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/jquery.colorbox-min.js",
                      "~/Scripts/main.js",
                      "~/Scripts/plugin.js",
                      "~/Scripts/global.js"));
```

**Modification**

When I visit web application and check its source code. I find below code added but with no css/JS code inside them.

```
 <link href="/Content/customcss?v=" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="/bundles/customjs?v="></script>
```

Comment: "Even physical files are not uploaded" - you mean actual `.css` and `.js` files?

Comment: yes that is right, I don't see these files on server using ftp.

Comment: Make sure that your `.css` and `.js` files have Build Action = Content. They must present on your server, otherwise bundles will have nothing to bundle (pardon my french).

Comment: Have you included those files in to your project solution?

Comment: Yes I have added in solution and can see them in solution explorer, I even copied them manually on server but somehow it is not linking and loading these files in the page. Am I missing any reference anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I find the solution thanks to @RJK for his clue

Previously I copied contents directly in the folder and later added them in VS, but somehow VS did not like it. I removed the contents from VS and physical folder and than add them again in solution and it worked.

```
=> Right click on Content -> Add -> Existing Item
=> Clean and rebuild and publish again.
```

I am still working to fixing the paths of images in css but that is another issue.

Lesson of the day, Never add any item outside of Visual Studio, even images you must add them in solution. VS would not automatically add them for you if you drop them in folder.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly your bundles will be generated (minified bundled etc.) on application_startup. There is no "physical" representation of those files. Just routes.